# I just resumed an Assassin's Creed save from months ago. How can I find out my objective?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I just resumed my Assassin's Creed 2 game, which I haven't played for several months.  The game loaded, and suddenly there's Ezio, standing in the middle of a crowded street, weapons in sleeves, with people milling about, and me with no idea where I am or who I'm supposed to kill.

I've looked through the ("Animus Desktop") - aka the Start menu, but I don't see Objectives anywhere.

**How can I figure out where I am and who I'm supposed to kill?**

Comment: Aren't there objective markers on the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the map (press Select from the game, or choose Map from the Animus). The diamond icons with the ! are the main missions. Hover over the other icons with the cursor to get a description of the other icons.

If you're mid-mission, you should have a coloured marker somewhere on the map which indicates your target.